# MySQL query to concatenate all the values in each row based on the common same id matching

Tags: mysql

Is there any way to concatenate the value in a field that matching with a common field say userid.

For eg if this is the table,

```
UserID | Field1 | Field2
1      | aaa    | zzz
1      | bbb    | yyy
1      | ccc    | xxx
```

i want it as a single row like

```
UserID | Field1        | Field2
1      | aaa, bbb, ccc | zzz, yyy, xxx
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mysql [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) aggregate function does this nicely.

```
SELECT UserID, GROUP_CONCAT(field1), GROUP_CONCAT(field2)
FROM Users
GROUP BY UserID
```

To get the order you require, you can specify the order to GROUP_CONCAT

```
SELECT UserID, GROUP_CONCAT(field1 ORDER BY field1,field2), GROUP_CONCAT(field2 ORDER BY field1, field2)
FROM Users
GROUP BY UserID
```

Answer (score 2):

You need [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

```
SELECT UserId GROUP_CONCAT(Field1) AS A, GROUP_CONCAT(Field2) AS B
FROM TBL
GROUP BY  UserId
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

```
SELECT UserID, GROUP_CONCAT(Field1), GROUP_CONCAT(Field2)
FROM table
GROUP BY UserID
```

Answer (score 1):

[GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

```
SELECT UserID, GROUP_CONCAT(Field1), GROUP_CONCAT(Field2)
FROM table
GROUP BY UserID
```